# How to calculate the sum of the values of arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, frontend, logic

I'm new to programming and I'm having trouble to make an array treatment in javascript (vue).

Here's the deal: I have 26 arrays with 4 elements each (values: a, b, c, d).

I have to sum the values according to their indexes, example:

{c, d, b, a} = c = 4, d = 3, b = 2, a = 1;

In the end I have to have an array with the sum of all these 26 objects, example:
[a = 104, b = 78, c = 52, d = 26]

What I currently have:

```
Array(26) [ (4) […], (4) […], (4) […], (4) […], (4) […], (4) […], (4) […], (4) […], (4) […], (4) […], … ]
```

​

```
this.array.forEach(item => {
    sum[item.value] = sum[item.value] + (i+1)
});
```

Edit: The objects of the array of 26 objects have value and description in different orders {b, a, d, c}, {a,d,b,c}, {a,b,c,d}... The indexes have "points" (value to sum), which is: the first index = 4 points, the second index = 3, the third = 2, the last = 1I have to sum the values of every single one and put in one array of the results.

So my expected result array is (for example):

```
[a = 104, b = 78, c = 52, d = 26]
```

Edit2: Sorry guys, I didn't understood at first what you were asking for.
My simplied input array:

```
Array(3) [
[
    {value: "a", description: "..."},
    {value: "b", description: "..."},
    {value: "c", description: "..."},
    {value: "d", description: "..."}
], 
[
    {value: "a", description: "..."},
    {value: "b", description: "..."},
    {value: "c", description: "..."},
    {value: "d", description: "..."}
], 
[
    {value: "a", description: "..."},
    {value: "b", description: "..."},
    {value: "c", description: "..."},
    {value: "d", description: "..."}
]]
```

I think it's more a logic problem, but I'm stuck at this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please give sample input and expected output? It's not clear to me exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi, You have array of arrays or array of objects?

Comment: @srk of course! I've made an edit

Comment: @YashMaheshwari please look at my edit, thanks for answering!

Comment: So, it means you have input in format `[{ 'b': 1, 'a': 1, 'd': 4, 'c': 2 }, {....}, ....]`, right?

Comment: I see the expected output, but where is the sample input?

Comment: @YashMaheshwari that's right

Comment: @srk there's no input, I have to treat the array of the 26 objects into a single one with the sum of the elements based on the values of the indexes

Comment: You haven't shown us an example of what exactly the array looks like. How are we supposed to answer the question without that information? Can you simplify the problem and post an array of 3 objects (including the details of those objects), along with the expected output?

Comment: do you have an array of objects or an array of arrays ? show a proper example input

Comment: *"There's no input, I have to treat the array of the 26 objects..."* - the "array of objects" is exactly the input that we are all asking about. It's the input to your algorithm. You've described it with words, but you haven't given a full example.

Comment: @srk sorry! edit2 made

Comment: @Jimmar I've made an edit2

Comment: Thanks all you guys for helping me out. My problem was solved <3

Comment: Please share the solution here, and accept it as an answer, so it might help someone :).

Answer (score 1):

To explain (possibly not very well) what this does:

For every inner array it's taking each object and converting it into an array like ['a', 3] where 'a' is the value from the object and the 3 is 4 minus its index (so that the scores should be 4, 3, 2, 1 for the four positions in the inner array). The inner arrays are then flattened so that these new arrays are all at the same level in an array. These new arrays are the processed through reduce to add up the scores by the value that we've stored in the array.

```js
const data = [
  [{ value: 'a' }, { value: 'b' }, { value: 'c' }, { value: 'd' }],
  [{ value: 'b' }, { value: 'c' }, { value: 'd' }, { value: 'a' }]
];

const res = data
  .flatMap( (scores) => scores.map(({ value }, i) => [value, 4 - i]) )
  .reduce(
    (acc, [key, score]) => Object.assign(acc, { [key]: acc[key] + score }),
    { a: 0, b: 0, c: 0, d: 0 }
  );

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't made a proper question at first, I've made an edit2 on the post, but your response was pretty close to what I need

Comment: life saver! Thanks a lottttttt

Comment: @gelene5745 if this answer solves your problem then please mark it as an accepted answer (the check mark on the left side under the arrows)